# keep getting error on line that doesnt exist anymore

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

while programming on jupyter notebook, i keep getting an unexpected EOF line. What ist strange is that I deleted that line and still get that error for the same line.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Copy the code to VS code to see whether some special chars appears or special format appears?

Comment: Share your code, so we can help you

Comment: Try saving and restarting

Comment: I already tried saving and restart. I even tried to create  a new notebook (without that line)and it still gives me the same error

Comment: Under 'kernel' at tool bar, you can try 'Restart and clear output'

Comment: @tianlinhe thank you so much! that worked :)

Answer (score 0):

@tianlinhe rightfully suggested to try "restart and clear output" which worked perfectly.
I just still dont know, why craeting a new notebook didnt work.

Comment: Because what you implemented was stored in RAM of your computer.